# Bash Script. Enter Username and Password

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I'm trying to write a script that calls another one. Then it should fill in username and password. Unfortunately spawn does not call my script file.

I created both scripts and then created them with 
`chmod +x filename.sh` made it executable.

vpn.sh

```
#! /usr/bin/expect

spawn ./startvpn.sh


#expect "[sudo] Passwort für niclas:"
#send "**********"

#expect "Enter Auth Username:"
#send '*************'

#expect "Enter Auth Password:"
#send "******"
```

startvpn.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp/se250.nordvpn.com.udp.ovpn
```

The plan:

I'm running ./vpn at the terminal,
which then executes startvpn. 
This establishes a connection with Openvpn.

Then vpn.sh should enter the Sudo password and then my username and password for NordVpn.

Strangely enough, startvpn never runs.

I don't get an error message.

**Update:**

I updated my script. Now it is working except it isnt entering the password.

updated version of vpn.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp/se250.nordvpn.com.udp.ovpn


expect "Passwort für niclas:"
send "******\r"

expect "Username:"
send "**************\r"

expect "Password:"
send "****\r"
```

The Console Output is:

```
niclas@niclas-Inspiron-7347:~$ expect vpn.sh 
spawn sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp/se250.nordvpn.com.udp.ovpn
[sudo] Passwort für niclas: 
Fri Jun 28 21:03:03 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019
Fri Jun 28 21:03:03 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Enter Auth Username: niclas.buerger@web.de
Enter Auth Password: niclas@niclas-Inspiron-7347:~$
```

If I type the password normally it will be filled in with ******.
So I really don't know why it doesn't work. The command is the same as the one with the username.

Comment: storing your password in a text file is extremely insecure.

Comment: Having said that, did you remember to "hit enter"? `send "password\r"`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. This Script is only running local on my PC so its the easiest solution for me to store it in a txt file. I d missed to hit enter, that's rigth. Thanks. But the main problem is that my startvpn.sh script is never executed when i  execute vpn.sh with ./vpn.sh.

Answer (score 0):

```
expect "[sudo] Passwort für niclas:"
```

Inside "" quote, [] will be act as tcl command subtitution syntax.

You need to use strict expect {} quite like:

```
expect {[sudo] Passwort für niclas:}
```

Or quote [] like:

```
expect "\[sudo\] Passwort für niclas:"
```

Or just use part of expected string:

```
expect "Passwort für niclas:"
```

Or just this:

```
expect "Passwort"
```

Comment: Thanks! Change it. Know its working but not entering the Password. See Updated Question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have another line after send. this is working for me:

> #!/usr/bin/expect -f
>
> spawn openconnect ********
>
> expect "Username:"
>
> send -- "********\r"
>
> expect "Password:"
>
> send -- "****\r"
>
> interact